# Angular2 DI javascript library

Tags: angular

How i can Inject any javascript library into component.
For instance i want to use Materialize framework in my angular2 app written in typescript.

[image: workaround]

This approach throws an error.

[image: not working]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, there are two parts:

- **For compilation**. You need to install the corresponding typings or make it available within your dependencies (`node_modules`). The files with extensions `.d.ts`
- **For runtime**. You need to configure the dependency in the module manager. For example SystemJS.

  See this question for example:

  - [integrating issue of ng2-material with Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35788918/integrating-issue-of-ng2-material-with-angular2/35789455#35789455).

---

See this question for more details:

- [Angular2 Cannot find module 'angular2/core' but application works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36400929/angular2-cannot-find-module-angular2-core-but-application-works/36401031#36401031)